# Advice with range function and or statements python for project euler 1

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am just trying to add up all the multiples of 3 and 5 up to 1000, while making sure that I do not add the coinciding multiples twice hence the or. I only want it to add the multiple of 5 if it is not a multiple of 3. I know I can just remove the overlapping multiples but I want to know how I could use an if statement to only add a multiple of 5 if it does not give remainder 0 when divided by 3.Thanks in advance

```
a=range(0, 1000,3 ) or range(0,1000,5)
b=sum(a)
print (b)
```

Comment: Well, remove the overlap. You add all of the multiples of 15 twice.

Comment: Wow, 3 simultaneous answers and all different!

Comment: This is Project Euler Problem 1 http://projecteuler.net/problem=1, please indicate that in your question.

Answer (score 4):

You can combine the two lists and get unique values from the union:

```
sum(set(range(0, 1000, 3) + range(0, 1000, 5)))
```

`set` is an unordered list of unique elements. So, here the two lists, one being multiples of 3 and another multiples of 5 are joined together; then converting this new list to `set` only keeps unique elements.

Comment: I had not thought of this at all, this is quite ingenious. For the askers sake, it might be worth adding a reason why this works, regarding the use of set to eliminate the duplicates.

Comment: Yes, What does set do?

Comment: The answer was edited to include a bit more details.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a list comprehension:

```
a = [x for x in range(1000) if ((x % 3 == 0) or (x % 5 == 0))]
b = sum(a)
```

Comment: Why not sum over generator comprehension `sum(x for x in range(1000) if ((x % 3 == 0) or (x % 5 == 0)))`?

Comment: @Akavall you could use a generator expression, although it would have to use `xrange` for python2

Answer (score 2):

You can just remove all multiples of 15.

This is a very brute force solution compared to the others, but its also quite simple.
Find the sum of all multiples of 3 and all multiples of 5. However you'll add the multiples of 15 *twice*, so remove those from the final sum:

```
total = sum(range(0, 1000,3)+range(0,1000,5))-sum(range(0,1000,15))
```

Comment: Thank you, I know I can just remove the overlapping multiples but I want to know how I could use an if statement to only add a multiple of 5 if it does not give remainder 0 when divided by 3.

Comment: Sure - `sum(i for i in range(1000) if i % 3 == 0 or i % 5 == 0)`.  There are many ways to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to do it with a grand total of 5 additions, 3 multiplications, 3 divisions, and trivial extra memory ;-)

```
def sumrange(start, stop, step):
    x = xrange(start, stop, step)
    if x:
        return (x[0] + x[-1]) * len(x) // 2
    else:
        return 0

print sumrange(0, 1000, 3) + sumrange(0, 1000, 5) - sumrange(0, 1000, 15)
```

This relies on that the sum of an arithmetic progression equals the number of elements in the progression times the average value (half the sum of the first and last elements).  All that can be done without constructing - or even generating - a list by using an `xrange` object (in Python 2 - use `range` in Python 3).

Comment: These seems a little complex and convoluted.

Comment: LOL - ya think? ;-)  But, as advertised, this is blazing fast and needs "no memory" even for stuff like `sumrange(1, 1000000000, 2)`.

Comment: Don't get me wrong. Not saying its bad, just complex, and at least worthy of an explanation of its merits.